# Using setInterval to pause a slideshow with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, slideshow, clearinterval

Firstly, I would like to say that I'm very new to JS/JQuery.

I'm trying to make a background image slideshow with a pause and play button.

I figured out how to pause it using clearInterval, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to resume again from the point where it paused. I know there are several threads about this but I can't get them to work with the slideshow.

Code following below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;
var images = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg"];
var image = $(".fader");
var timer = false;


image.css("background-image","url("+images[3]+")");

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(500, function(){
        image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
        image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count==images.length){
        count = 0;
    }
},1000);

$("#pauseButton").click(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
 });

 $("#startButton").click(function(){
     setInterval(timer);
});
```

});

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you make your "next slide" function reusable, then use it whenever you need to start the slideshow, whether that's the initial start or later when you're re-starting.

But putting the various bits of logic in discrete, well-named functions can help the code flow more easily and be simpler to read/maintain, here are some suggestions (marked with `***`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg"];
    var image = $(".fader");
    var timer = 0; // *** Timer handles are numbers. `false` works, but...

    // *** Reusable function to target with `setInterval`
    function nextSlide() {
        image.fadeOut(500, function() {
            image.css("background-image", "url(" + images[count] + ")"); // *** Removed increment here, see below
            image.fadeIn(500);
        });
        count = (count + 1) % images.length; // *** Easy way to do roll-around
    }

    // *** Reusable "start" function
    function startSlideShow() {
        if (!timer) { // *** Don't try to start it if already running
            timer = setInterval(nextSlide, 1000);
        }
    }

    // *** Reusable "stop" function
    function stopSlideShow() {
        clearInterval(timer); // *** Safe to call with `0`, so no need to branch
        timer = 0;
    }

    // *** Stop when pause button clicked
    $("#pauseButton").click(stopSlideShow);

    // *** (Re)Start when pause button clicked
    $("#startButton").click(startSlideShow);

    // *** Start the slideshow automatically
    image.css("background-image", "url(" + images[3] + ")");
    startSlideShow();
});
```